# VPN server on Debian 10 using L2TP with IPSEC PSK not working

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vpn, android

I am trying to make a VPN server on Debian 10 server that would enable Windows 10 and Android clients to connect using L2TP over IPSEC with pre-shared key (PSK).

The same client(s) work successfully with Ubiquity UDM-Pro Dream Machine's VPS server with simple GUI config, as tested from equally Windows 10 and Android Samsung Galaxy A12 and Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite.

I am new to libreswan. The version I'm using is the default 3.27-6+deb10u1.

I am trying to assign an IP address from the range 192.168.100.10-192.168.100.253 on eth1 from our preexisting DHCP pool, which is accessible over the NAT and the host presents itself as 161.53.235.3 (to the world) and as 192.168.100.1 (to hosts behind the NAT).

(This is handy because authenticated clients could "see" their business PCs and connect via RDP, which is the basic idea.)

Thank you kindly for considering this request.

The NAT is configured as follows:

```
root@domac:/home/admin/mtodorov# iptables-save -t nat
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Mon Nov 22 14:26:47 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [17288678:2026230352]
:INPUT ACCEPT [10182155:755518594]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2533708:173476436]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [9707250:822554753]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 161.53.235.3
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Nov 22 14:26:47 2021
root@domac:/home/admin/mtodorov#
```

My configuration is as follows:

```
# /etc/ipsec.conf - Libreswan IPsec configuration file
#
# see 'man ipsec.conf' and 'man pluto' for more information
#
# For example configurations and documentation, see https://libreswan.org/wiki/

config setup
    # Normally, pluto logs via syslog.
    logfile=/var/log/pluto.log
    #
    # Do not enable debug options to debug configuration issues!
    #
    # plutodebug="control parsing"
    plutodebug="all crypt"
    # plutodebug=none
    #
    # NAT-TRAVERSAL support
    # exclude networks used on server side by adding %v4:!a.b.c.0/24
    # It seems that T-Mobile in the US and Rogers/Fido in Canada are
    # using 25/8 as "private" address space on their wireless networks.
    # This range has never been announced via BGP (at least up to 2015)
    virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12,%v4:25.0.0.0/8,%v4:100.64.0.0/10,%v6:fd00::/8,%v6:fe80::/10,%v4:192.198.186.218/32

# if it exists, include system wide crypto-policy defaults
# include /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/libreswan.config

# It is best to add your IPsec connections as separate files in /etc/ipsec.d/
include /etc/ipsec.d/*.conf
```

My `/etc/ipsec.d/l2tp-psk.conf` is as follows:

```
conn L2TP-PSK-NAT
    rightsubnet=vhost:%priv
    also=L2TP-PSK-noNAT

conn L2TP-PSK-noNAT
    # Use a Preshared Key. Disable Perfect Forward Secrecy.
    authby=secret
    pfs=no
    auto=add
    keyingtries=3
    # we cannot rekey for %any, let client rekey
    rekey=no
    # Apple iOS doesn't send delete notify so we need dead peer detection
    # to detect vanishing clients
    dpddelay=10
    dpdtimeout=30
    dpdaction=clear
    # Set ikelifetime and keylife to same defaults windows has
    ikelifetime=8h
    keylife=1h
    # l2tp-over-ipsec is transport mode
    type=transport
    #
    # left will be filled in automatically with the local address of the default-route interface (as determined at IPsec startup time).
    left=%defaultroute
    #
    # For updated Windows 2000/XP clients,
    # to support old clients as well, use leftprotoport=17/%any
    leftprotoport=17/1701
    #
    # The remote user.
    #
    right=%any
    # Using the magic port of "%any" means "any one single port". This is
    # a work around required for Apple OSX clients that use a randomly
    # high port.
    rightprotoport=17/%any
```

My `/etc/ipsec.d/domac-alu.secrets` is:

```
%any : PSK "<mysecret>"
```

My `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets` is

```
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client        server  secret                  IP addresses
mtodorov * <mypasswd> *
# end.
```

My `/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf` is:

```
[global]
listen-addr = 161.53.235.3
ipsec saref = no
access control = no
debug network = yes
debug tunnel = yes

[lns default]
ip range = 192.168.100.10-192.168.100.253
local ip = 192.168.100.1
refuse chap = yes
refuse pap = yes
require authentication = yes
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/xl2tpd-options
length bit = yes
```

My `/etc/ppp/xl2tpd-options` is:

```
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
require-mschap-v2
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
```

The error message from Windows 10 is like this:

[image: VPN L2TP with IPSEC PSK error msg]

The error log from /var/log/pluto.log for the event is:

[Session log 1](https://domac.alu.hr/mtodorov/xl2tpd-ipsec-20211122.log)

Here is the one with **crypto** debug turned off:

[Session log 2](https://domac.alu.hr/mtodorov/xl2tpd-ipsec-20211122-nocrypt.log)

Please any help? I am running out of options and this has to work ... We are required to establish a VPN for people working from home in this COVID situation ...

(Peer **193.198.186.218** in logs is also my client PC.)

xl2tpd log is as follows:

```
Nov 22 14:48:57 domac xl2tpd[26982]: IPsec SAref does not work with L2TP kernel mode yet, enabling force userspace=yes
Nov 22 14:48:57 domac xl2tpd[26982]: Not looking for kernel SAref support.
Nov 22 14:48:57 domac xl2tpd[26979]: Starting xl2tpd: xl2tpd.
Nov 22 14:48:57 domac xl2tpd[26982]: Not looking for kernel support.
Nov 22 14:48:57 domac xl2tpd[26983]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.3.12 started on domac PID:26983
Nov 22 14:48:57 domac xl2tpd[26983]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 1998, Adtran, Inc.
Nov 22 14:48:57 domac xl2tpd[26983]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001
Nov 22 14:48:57 domac xl2tpd[26983]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002
Nov 22 14:48:57 domac xl2tpd[26983]: Forked again by Xelerance (www.xelerance.com) (C) 2006-2016
Nov 22 14:48:57 domac xl2tpd[26983]: Listening on IP address 161.53.235.3, port 1701
```

Thank you very much in forward.

Comment: Not an answer but I cannot help myself... IPsec implementations have glorious amount of interoperability issues, not even mentioning open/libre/strong-swan hell. Use OpenVPN if you can (UDM should support it btw), save yourself a headache. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got resolved with a lot of drudgeries, so I thought of posting an answer.

The problem was in the firewall in between. I couldn't have solved it in a million years unless I turned to our academic network NOC people, and they claimed they had it all passed. Then I got a laptop from which the same configuration worked over the wireless, wifi hotspot and our commercial ISP, but it did not work with our academic network.

Then they did something, and it suddenly started working without a change on my behalf.

The last config that worked, approved by the libreswan developers, was this one:

/etc/ipsec.d/l2tp-psk.conf:

```
conn L2TP-PSK-NAT
        rightsubnet=vhost:%priv
        also=L2TP-PSK-common

conn L2TP-PSK-noNAT
        rightsubnet=vhost:%no
        also=L2TP-PSK-common

conn L2TP-PSK-common
        # Use a Preshared Key. Disable Perfect Forward Secrecy.
        authby=secret
        pfs=no
        auto=add
        keyingtries=3
        # we cannot rekey for %any, let client rekey
        rekey=no
        # Apple iOS doesn't send delete notify so we need dead peer detection
        # to detect vanishing clients
        dpddelay=10
        dpdtimeout=30
        dpdaction=clear
        # Set ikelifetime and keylife to same defaults windows has
        ikelifetime=8h
        keylife=1h
        ikev2=never
        #ike = aes256-sha1-modp1024!
        # l2tp-over-ipsec is transport mode
        type=transport
        #
        # left will be filled in automatically with the local address of the default-route interface (as determined at IPsec startup time).
        left=%defaultroute
        #
        # For updated Windows 2000/XP clients,
        # to support old clients as well, use leftprotoport=17/%any
        leftprotoport=17/1701
        #
        # The remote user.
        #
        right=%any
        # Using the magic port of "%any" means "any one single port". This is
        # a work around required for Apple OSX clients that use a randomly
        # high port.
        rightprotoport=17/%any
```

The key change (received from developers) was this:
`rightsubnet=vhost:%no` for noNAT connection.

All other config is valid then.
I hope this helps someone.

Kind regards,
Marvin